# Data is inserted but wont retrieve using Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Trying to fetch the data from the server using Retrofit and caching it offline using Room Database.

**Problem** I have fetched the data from the server and inserted it into the room but could not populate it. After evaluating the expression, the LiveData list is null.

I am certain that the insertion is successful, as I went through some answers on StackOverflow which mentioned to return the list of IDs to find out if there has been an insert.

Below is my code:

**User.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Long,

    @Json(name = "name")
    val uname:String,
    val username:String,
    val email:String,
    @Embedded
    val address: Address,
    val phone:String,
    val website:String,
    @Embedded
    val company: Company)

data class Address(
    val street:String,
    val suite:String,
    val city:String,
    val zipcode:String,
    @Embedded
    val geo: Geo)

data class Geo(
    val lat:String,
    val lng:String)

data class Company(
    @Json(name = "name")
    val companyName:String,
    val catchPhrase:String,
    val bs:String)
```

**UserDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface UserDao{

    @Query("select * from user_table")
    fun getUserList():LiveData<List<User>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(userList:List<User>):List<Long>
}
```

**UserRepository.kt**

```
class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {

    val userList: LiveData<List<User>> = userDao.getUserList()

    suspend fun refreshUserList() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val userList = UserApi.retrofitService.getUserData().await()

            val list = userDao.insertAll(userList)
            Log.e("list","${list.size}")

        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivityViewModel.kt**

```
class MainActivityViewModel(database:UserDao, application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){

    private val userRepository = UserRepository(database)
    val usersList = userRepository.userList

    private var viewModelJob = Job()
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Main)

    init {
        getUsersList()
    }

    private fun getUsersList() {

        coroutineScope.launch {

            try{

                userRepository.refreshUserList()

            }catch (networkError: IOException){
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
        //Main View Model Destroys
    }
}
```

**UserAdapter.kt**

```
class UserAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    var userDetailsList:List<User> = emptyList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        return ViewHolder(UserCellLayoutBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        ))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userDetailsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val user = userDetailsList[position]
        holder.bind(user)
    }

    class ViewHolder(private var binding: UserCellLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(user: User){
            binding.user = user
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityViewModel
    private var adapter:UserAdapter ?= null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        val dataSource = UserRoomDatabase.getInstance(application).userDao
        viewModelFactory = ViewModelFactory(dataSource,application)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.mainActivityViewModel = viewModel
        binding.executePendingBindings()
        binding.userListRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.usersList.observe(this, Observer<List<User>> {users ->
            users?.apply {
                adapter?.userDetailsList = users
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point in the usersList.observe call? Is the LiveData never updating? I also would have used something like
viewModel.usersList.observe(this, Observer { users ->
            users?.let {
                adapter?.userDetailsList = it
            }
        }) instead of apply

Comment: @bitjuggler thanks for your response, the live data only observes for the first time after that the debug never comes on it. Also tried to observe the list as you did but still no success

Comment: how do you consume the **Json** response with Retrofit ? what 
 is in your *addConverterFactory()* method ? what is the list size when  *onResponse()* callback is called ?

Comment: @OmarBeshary I have used moshi converter factory for deserialization of objects. I got the list size as 10 after a successful response. Here is the [api which I have consumed](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)

Comment: I am not sure about this, but in UserRepository.kt you are defining val userList as LiveData and then in your suspend fun your are using the same variable name for the fetch. Maybe there is some kind of conflict here? One more thing: You are only logging the list size after the insert. Did you check if the list of Long is correctly yielding 0, 1, 2, 3, ... since you are using autoGenerate=true

Comment: @bitjuggler finally solved the issue, didn't know how i missed on this one **I forgot to instantiate the adapter** , so every time the list was being observed my adapter was null. silly mistake from my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to instantiate the adapter in **MainActivity.kt**

adapter = UserAdapter()

```
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        val dataSource = UserRoomDatabase.getInstance(application).userDao
        viewModelFactory = ViewModelFactory(dataSource,application)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.mainActivityViewModel = viewModel
        binding.executePendingBindings()

        adapter = UserAdapter()

        binding.userListRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.usersList.observe(this, Observer<List<User>> {users ->
            users?.apply {
                adapter?.userDetailsList = users
            }
        })
```